# Deployment of Zeno Field 3.11 in windows 8.1

Tags: gps

Is it possible to install Zeno Field 3.11 in windows 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, Zeno Field 3.11 or the latest version 3.2 is not supported on Windows 8.x. I have personally tested version 3.2 with Windows 8 and was able to connect to the GG03 SmartAntenna and receive 1cm accuracy when using corrections from a real-time network in a current project. I did not test much beyond that, but initial testing was successful.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://www.leica-geosystems.us/downloads123/zz/gpsgis/Zeno%20Field%20&%20Office/brochures-datasheet/Leica_Zeno_Field_Office_DS_en.pdf), Windows 8.x is not supported.  Whether or not it will work on Windows 8.1 is a different story.

```
Platform: PC-Intel 
Operating System: Windows Vista, Windows 2000, Windows XP or Windows 7 
Memory: minimum 1 GB RAM, 2 GB recommended
Processor: 1.6 GHz or higher
2.4 GB free disk space for Zeno Office or 200 MB for Zeno Office on ArcGIS DVD Rom for installation
```